# There is something wrong, the problem is in the transition. There is a problem when a layout will be visible, invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication

There is something wrong with this place. It means it works properly. But the problem is in the transition. There is a problem when a layout will be visible, invisible .

```
if (edittext1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    textview3.setTextColor(0xFFFF1744);
    final ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(linear3,
                                                                           "backgroundColor",
                                                                           new ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                                           0xffEEEEEE,
                                                                           0xffFF1744);
    backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(500);
    backgroundColorAnimator.start();
}
else {
    if (textview6.getText().toString().equals("Get password reset link")) {
        _telegramLoaderDialog(true);
        firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(edittext1.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(_firebaseAuth_reset_password_listener);
    }
    else {
        if (edittext2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            textview4.setTextColor(0xFFFF1744);
            final ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(linear4,
                                                                                   "backgroundColor",
                                                                                   new ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                                                   0xffEEEEEE,
                                                                                   0xffFF1744);
            backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(500);
            backgroundColorAnimator.start();
        }
        else {
            if (Current) {
                if (edittext3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    textview9.setTextColor(0xFFFF1744);
                    final ObjectAnimator backgroundColorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(linear7,
                                                                                           "backgroundColor",
                                                                                           new ArgbEvaluator(),
                                                                                           0xffEEEEEE,
                                                                                           0xffFF1744);
                    backgroundColorAnimator.setDuration(500);
                    backgroundColorAnimator.start();
                }
                else {
                    _autoTransitionScroll(vscroll1);
                    linear8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textview6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textview7.setEnabled(false);
                    checkbox1.setEnabled(false);
                    edittext1.setEnabled(false);
                    edittext2.setEnabled(false);
                    edittext3.setEnabled(false);
                    if (edittext2.getText().toString().equals(edittext3.getText().toString())) {
                        if (checkbox1.isChecked()) {
                            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(AuthActivity.this, _firebaseAuth_create_user_listener);
                        }
                        else {
                            _autoTransitionScroll(vscroll1);
                            linear8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            textview6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            textview7.setEnabled(true);
                            checkbox1.setEnabled(true);
                            edittext1.setEnabled(true);
                            edittext2.setEnabled(true);
                            edittext3.setEnabled(true);
                            LayoutInflater Inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                            
                            View InfView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.success_toast, null);
                            
                            LinearLayout border = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById(R.id.border);
                            
                            LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
                            
                            LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById (R.id.line);
                            
                            TextView title = (TextView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                            
                            TextView content = (TextView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.content);
                            
                            ImageView image_logo = (ImageView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.image_logo);
                            
                            Toast ToastName = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            
                            ToastName.setView(InfView);
                            
                            ToastName.show();
                            image_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.info1);
                            title.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/en_med.ttf"), 1);
                            content.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/en_light.ttf"), 0);
                            _RoundAndBorder(border, "#2F87EB", 0, "#ffffff", 8);
                            _SX_CornerRadius_4(line, "#80ffffff", "#80ffffff", 0, 0, 8, 0, 8);
                            title.setText("Attention Please!");
                            content.setText("Agree with our Privacy Policy and T&Cs to continue creating an account.");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        _autoTransitionScroll(vscroll1);
                        linear8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textview6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textview7.setEnabled(true);
                        checkbox1.setEnabled(true);
                        edittext1.setEnabled(true);
                        edittext2.setEnabled(true);
                        edittext3.setEnabled(true);
                        LayoutInflater Inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        
                        View InfView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.success_toast, null);
                        
                        LinearLayout border = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById(R.id.border);
                        
                        LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
                        
                        LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) InfView.findViewById (R.id.line);
                        
                        TextView title = (TextView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                        
                        TextView content = (TextView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.content);
                        
                        ImageView image_logo = (ImageView) InfView.findViewById(R.id.image_logo);
                        
                        Toast ToastName = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        
                        ToastName.setView(InfView);
                        
                        ToastName.show();
                        image_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.info1);
                        title.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/en_med.ttf"), 1);
                        content.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/en_light.ttf"), 0);
                        _RoundAndBorder(border, "#2F87EB", 0, "#ffffff", 8);
                        _SX_CornerRadius_4(line, "#80ffffff", "#80ffffff", 0, 0, 8, 0, 8);
                        title.setText("Attention Please!");
                        content.setText("The Passwords you've entered does not match! Please check and try again.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(AuthActivity.this, _firebaseAuth_sign_in_listener);
                _autoTransitionScroll(vscroll1);
                linear8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textview6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textview7.setEnabled(false);
                checkbox1.setEnabled(false);
                edittext1.setEnabled(false);
                edittext2.setEnabled(false);
                edittext3.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The animation problem in line if anyone figure out please help me. I try it several times but the animator loding screen not working properly.

Comment: Your question is too unclear. We know something does not work but hard to figure out what exactly. Would you be able to produce a minimal working example of what does not work?

Comment: thanks for comment i slove the problem

Comment: Now a new problem. Fab is not working. it shows a Click Runtime Error.